# Plotting NA values in a Scatter Plot using R

Tags: r, na

[image][Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LZoUb4feEUeDkyKX9eiCldFL6wjDF5Y8/view?usp=sharing)

I have a dataset which has 140 rows and 17 columns. I wanna visualize all values including NA in the scatterplot showing Secchi vs Hu Angle. When I did try to visualize it with asthetics such as color, shape and size, it show me only the points which has values. But, it doesnt show null values. I also tried adding 0 instead of Null, and it worked. But, I dont wanna add zero. Is it possible to show all the values including null values.

[image]

Most of the Null values are in Wave.height field.

I have tried to show NUll values in the plot added Zero and median values instead of NA values and it showed me all the values. But, I wanna show all the values including NA values.

```
final_updated_4 <- read.csv("final_updated_4.csv")
###Outliers###
### Wave height vs Sun vs Wind Speed###
ggplot(final_updated_4, aes(x= hue_angle, y=Secchi))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Sun, color=Wave.height, size= Wind.speed))+
  ylab("Secchi")+
  xlab("Hue Angle")+
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10), oob = scales::squish)+
  geom_abline(yintercept=0, slope=1, linetype="dashed")+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey60"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.0, "cm"))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y~x,aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE,
               rr.digits = 5)"""
```

Comment: How exactly would you like the null values to be displayed? Also, please dont upload your data as images (or via a link), but instead edit your question to include reproducible code. For some tips, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Actually, from my plot its seems like I worked only with 20 stations from where i collected but actually I have 140 station. I just wanted to show all the data in the plot. Lets say for the wind.speed , can one more class NA. This doesnt have much affect on my result but it will show I worked with a large dataset. I removed my original dataset and tried with few data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [naniar::](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/getting-started-w-naniar.html) package

Example

```
ggplot(airquality, 
       aes(x = Solar.R, 
           y = Ozone)) + 
  geom_miss_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~Month)
```

[image]